# Decorated/Computed arrays in Angular2

Tags: design-patterns, angular

I have a component, which i want to use like this

```
<comp [list]="['alpha', 'bravo', 'charlie']"></comp>
```

i.e, i want it to display the contents of a list.

The compontent's code is

```
@Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="item of decoratedList()">
          {{ item.name }} - {{ item.foo }} - {{ item.bar }}
        </li>
      </ul>`
})
class Comp {
    list: any[];

    decoratedList(): any[] {
        return this.list.map(item => ({
          name: item,
          foo: fooIt(item),
          bar: barIt(item)
       }));
    }
}
```

The Problem with this code is `decoratedList`, because it returns a new list every check, due to it's use of `map`, which leads to `decoratedList() has Changed`-type errors.

What is an ideomatic way in angular to handle such a pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways:

- Assign the result of `decoratedList()` to a property and bind the view to that property

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="item of decoratedList">
          {{ item.name }} - {{ item.foo }} - {{ item.bar }}
        </li>
      </ul>`
})
class Comp {
    @Input() list: any[];

    updateDecoratedList(): any[] {
        this.decoratedList = this.list.map(item => ({
          name: item,
          foo: fooIt(item),
          bar: barIt(item)
       }));
    }

    // only called when a different list was passed, not when the content of the array changed
    ngOnChanges() {
      this.updateDecoratedList();
    }
}
```

or use `IterableDiffers` and `ngDoCheck` to also check for changes in the content of `list`

```ts
@Component({
    selector: 'comp',
    template: `
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="item of decoratedList">
          {{ item.name }} - {{ item.foo }} - {{ item.bar }}
        </li>
      </ul>`
})
class Comp {
    @Input() list: any[];
    differ: any;

    constructor(differs: IterableDiffers) {
        this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);
    }

    updateDecoratedList(): any[] {
        this.decoratedList = this.list.map(item => ({
          name: item,
          foo: fooIt(item),
          bar: barIt(item)
       }));
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
      var changes = this.differ.diff(this.list);
      if (changes) {
        this.updateDecoratedList();
      }
    }
}
```

- make `decoratedList()` cache the result in a property and only return a new one if some dependent value (`list`) has changed. For this strategy also `IterableDiffer` can be used to check for changes in the content of `list`.